# Access 2010 SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need a query that return values from the beginning of the current month until today.

For example :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #1/6/2016# AND Now();
```

But I need this query to work not just this month...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a given date, you could use the [`DATESERIAL()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateserial.php) function to grab the first day of a given month :

```
SELECT *
  FROM Orders
 WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN DATESERIAL(Year(YourDate), Month(YourDate), 1) AND NOW()
```

If you were able to explicitly pass in the month and year, you could do that as well :

```
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN DATESERIAL(2016, 6, 1) AND NOW()
```